# Two smoothly homotopic smooth maps induce same maps on de Rham cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $a$, $b: M \to N$ be smoothly homotopic smooth maps. How do I see directly that $a$ and $b$ induce the same maps on de Rham cohomology? I know I want to construct a suitable chain homotopy between complexes of forms, but I am at a loss at how to do so. Could anybody help?

Comment: The answer to your question is well explained in "Godbillon, éléments de topologie algébrique, p.164"